# Qustions on the orbits of weyl group and group actions

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, weyl-group, symmetric-spaces

I am an undergraduate in physics and know little about math. I know about some basic ideas of Lie groups and Lie algebras like roots, weyl group, weyl chambers but I am ignorant about complexification, symmetric space and so on.  When I was reading the paper *A geometric theory of non-local two-qubit operations*https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0209120, I was confused with the maths the author used.

It says at the bottom of page8 in this paper *"From the Lie group representation theory, the orbits of local gates $K$ acting on $SU(4)/SU(2)\otimes SU(2)$ are in one-to-one correspondence with the orbits of the Weyl group $W(G,K)$ on $\mathfrak{a}$"*. (the ref is *differential geometry, Lie groups and symmetric spaces*) But I didn't find the theorem in this book. It may be in Chap7. Actually, I didn't know the definitions of those two actions.

What are the definitions of those two actions? Where can I find this theorem?